# How can I make quicksearch use multiple criteria?

Tags: jquery, quick-search

I have the quicksearch plugin for jquery working on an input, to allow a table to be filtered:

```
$('input#table-filter').quicksearch('table tbody tr');
```

However, I would now like to make an adjustment whereby a user can type in multiple criteria (e.g. using a text area, with each term on a separate line), and the filter shows all rows that match *any* of the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though all you have to do is add an option to it.

```
$('#table-filter').quicksearch('table tbody tr',{ 
    prepareQuery: function(val){
        return val.toLowerCase().split('\n');
    }
});
```

https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch/blob/master/jquery.quicksearch.js#L24

this causes it to split the input value on new line rather than space.

Comment: That would work if splitting the values with a space (in the default setup) allowed for multiple criteria, but it just doesn't.
If you look at this example: http://bio.mq.edu.au/Tools/jquery/plugins/riklomas-quicksearch/examples/ and try entering two criteria separated by a space (e.g. "devo muffin"), it doesn't work.

Comment: Then you may need to also pass in a callback for the `testQuery` method. The way the plugin is written, it's very extensible, most of the important methods can be overridden by simply passing in an option.